# How to set up NX for AWS lambdas with CDK?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, nomachine-nx

I have a NX monorepo with React app and CDK setup using `@ago-dev/nx-aws-cdk-v2`. I'm trying to set up some lambdas in the project but can't find any generators for lambdas with cdk. There are couple but they all use Serverless framework.

Anyone got it set up or has any idea how to best set it up?

Comment: I think there is no generator for this plugin only a very convenient way to create a CDK app in an NX monorepo, and then configure deploy/destroy and bootstrap the environment

Comment: Take a look at the different Lambda constructs in CDK. Pretty straight forward. You just need a folder with a handler.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, currently you can only do a few commands relating to a new CDK project, such as generate, boostrap, deploy and destroy an application.

https://github.com/adrian-goe/nx-aws-cdk-v2/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk-v2/README.md

For Lambdas, you need to create them yourself.

My approach, in the cdk `src` folder:

- I have another directory called `functions`
- Each child directory of `functions` is a lambda, followed by an `index.ts` (or js if you are not using Typescript)

From there, you can create your lambda within your stack